# Calling causes freeze

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, calls

I own a Samsung Galaxy S2 I9100, currently running Android 4.0.3 XWLP7, rooted. My problems however started even before rooting the phone.

The problem is that whenever I try to call someone, there is about a 20% chance that the phone will freeze, sometimes for over a minute(!), without performing any action. I can hide the Phone application by pressing the home button, but the app itself is frozen and unresponsive. After some time passes, the call is made, even if I've hidden the Phone app by pressing the home button.

All other apps seem to work without any issues. The phone is otherwise completely usable and no other defects can be observed.

A while ago after googling, I found a thread on xda-developers that recommended clearing the data of "Call settings" from Settings -> Applications -> All. At the time I believed this to solve my problem, but the problem reappeared pretty soon, and I do not believe it to be relevant at all now.

I have tried restoring my phone to factory state, including deleting everything from the phone storage and reinstalling the OS, without any effect on the issue.

Is this a known issue, and if so, are there any remedies?

Comment: Have you installed any call recording software?

Comment: No, I haven't installed any app that should have anything to do with that.

Comment: Try upgrading to ICS 4.0.4, the previous version 4.0.3 was known to be a little bit troublesome.

Comment: Why do you not try using another ROM? I have had that issues with some ROMs earlier and usually it was just due to a faulty calling app. Another good idea would be to try a different app to replace the dialer. Eg. Dialer+ or Contacts+

Comment: @AdityaSomani That's what I ended doing - re-flashing and it worked. I have not answered the question, though, since I think it's not really an answer...

Comment: @K.Steff I agree. That is not a solution per se to the problem. I hope we can find a solution to the same in case something like this happens again. Did you try replacing the Dialer? Did that help?

Comment: @AdityaSomani Yes, it worked OK with alternative dialers, though I was too fond of the default one, so I replaced the ROM.

Comment: Have same problem reset to factory, but no go...
Strangely I didn't have this issue until recently and don't have any special apps installed, as I said I just reset to factory. I have a Galaxy Beam, which for the most part is identical with the S2 just that it has a projector embedded

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a screen protector or is the light sensor dirty or obstructed? This is how i fixed mine!!! My phone did the same thing. Screen would go black when making or receiving calls. Audio still worked but the phone was inoperable in every other way during this malfunction. i realized those little sensors were dirty and partially blocked, after cleaning the obstruction the phone was PERFECT!

Comment: While sensors (not sure about light sensors, but usually proximity sensors) may turn off the screen to prevent accidental touch, the symptoms described in the question look different. unless "freezing" = "screen turned off".